# WCF ignore data contract not working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF Service hosted on IIS. Here is my Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
public interface IETC
{
   [OperationContract]
   [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "XYZ")]
   string GetStampXML();

   [OperationContract]
   [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "XYZ")]
   List<Stamp> GetStamps();
}
```

I am getting an error when I go to my WCF service through the web browser. The error is as follows:

```
Type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute.....
```

My stamps Class is:

```
[DataContract]
public class Stamp
{
    private string _Name;
    private string _SmallIcon = "";
    private string _MediumIcon = "";
    private string _LargeIcon = "";

    private BitmapImage _SmallImage;
    private BitmapImage _MediumImage;
    private BitmapImage _LargeImage;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string SmallIcon
    {
        get { return _SmallIcon; }
        set { _SmallIcon = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string MediumIcon
    {
        get { return _MediumIcon; }
        set { _MediumIcon = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string LargeIcon
    {
        get { return _LargeIcon; }
        set { _LargeIcon = value; }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public BitmapImage SmallImage
    {
        get { return _SmallImage; }
        set { _SmallImage = value; }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public BitmapImage MediumImage
    {
        get { return _MediumImage; }
        set { _MediumImage = value; }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public BitmapImage LargeImage
    {
        get { return _LargeImage; }
        set { _LargeImage = value; }
    }
}
```

It is like the IgnoreDataMember is not being recognized. I tried it without the IgnoreDataMember figure it was going to only serialize the DataMembers, and that didn't work either. Any ideas why it seems to trying to serialize the BitmapImage?

Comment: You shouldn't need the IgnoreDataMember attribute, when you specify DataContract on an object only the properties with a DataMember attribute is set on the class. You should check your service interface, perhaps you're using the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContract serializer.

Comment: I tried without explicitly adding the IgnoreDataMember as well with no luck. How would I know I am using the XmlSerializer? I thought that the DataContract attribute would make it use the DataCotnract serializer.

Comment: I just realized your error message says 'Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute' which should come from the DataContract serializer. So that's probably OK. The code you posted looks OK as well, so the error is probably somewhere else in one of the other objects used in your service interface. You should be aware that objects not marked with DataContract will serialize all public properties by default. You could try serializing a test object outside WCF first. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What version of .net are you running? .NET 4 Data Contract does not require you to explicitly set Ignore attributes. You can test what's being produced by using DataContractSerializer and writing the content to the file. Create console application and reference your service project.

```
namespace SO_10281928
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var instance = new Stamp
                               {
                                   Name = "Test",
                                   SmallIcon = "Small Icon",
                                   LargeIcon = "LargeIcon",
                                   MediumIcon = "MediumIcon"
                               };

            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\stamp.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                var ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (Stamp));
                ds.WriteObject(stream, instance);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Stamp
    {
        private string _Name;
        private string _SmallIcon = "";
        private string _MediumIcon = "";
        private string _LargeIcon = "";

        private BitmapImage _SmallImage;
        private BitmapImage _MediumImage;
        private BitmapImage _LargeImage;

        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string SmallIcon
        {
            get { return _SmallIcon; }
            set { _SmallIcon = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string MediumIcon
        {
            get { return _MediumIcon; }
            set { _MediumIcon = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string LargeIcon
        {
            get { return _LargeIcon; }
            set { _LargeIcon = value; }
        }

        public BitmapImage SmallImage
        {
            get { return _SmallImage; }
            set { _SmallImage = value; }
        }

        public BitmapImage MediumImage
        {
            get { return _MediumImage; }
            set { _MediumImage = value; }
        }

        public BitmapImage LargeImage
        {
            get { return _LargeImage; }
            set { _LargeImage = value; }
        }
    }

    public class BitmapImage
    {
    }
}
```

And the result is :

```
<Stamp xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SO_10281928" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <LargeIcon>LargeIcon</LargeIcon>
    <MediumIcon>MediumIcon</MediumIcon>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <SmallIcon>Small Icon</SmallIcon>
</Stamp>
```

Comment: That is what I expected to happen as well. Maybe it has something to do with my Stamp class being in a Silverlight Library and me using it in a .NET 4 WCF project?